# MySQL Daemon Lock issue

Tags: mysql, sockets, debian

Last night, my MySQL server went down unexpectedly. On attempting to restart (with `service mysql restart` - I'm root) it merely hangs. With the `mysql -u root -p` command, I get:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2).

I then tried to start the daemon manually (`mysqld`). The prompt would hang for about 2 seconds, and then return. On closer inspection of the error logs, I got:

`2016-01-22T19:18:32.399584Z 0 [ERROR] Could not create unix socket lock file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock.lock.`

`2016-01-22T19:18:32.399622Z 0 [ERROR] Unable to setup unix socket lock file.`

`2016-01-22T19:18:32.399646Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting`

I then tried `chown mysql /var/run/mysqld`, `chmod -R 775 /var/run/mysqld` and `apt-get install mysql-community-server --reinstall`. No luck.

I have looked around, and couldn't find a solution. Any help here?

Note: I am Running Debian 8 (Jessie) with MySQL community Server 5.7.10

Comment: Run this: `touch /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock.lock` and later `service mysql start`....

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work - I get the same error in the log file (`[ERROR] Could not create unix socket lock file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock.lock.`)

Comment: Try running: `chmod -R 755 /var/run/mysqld/`

Comment: Did you read the post? I said I did that. It's fixed now anyway: http://serverfault.com/questions/751277/mysql-daemon-lock-issue. I guess I should update it on here.

Comment: I skip that part...sorry, you don't need to be that rude...where are trying to help...anyway, your fix is more like a patch than an actual solution...

Comment: Sorry if I came across as rude. If anyone has a better solution I'd **love** to hear it, but it doesn't really matter if you're not locking the directory, does it?

Comment: Note to future travelers: It depends on your specific configuration but this is *very* likely an issue with apparmor. If you don't want to disable locking take a look at syslog and see if you're getting apparmor denies on that file.

Comment: Except... I didn't have AppArmor. Also, yay for necroposting!

Comment: For anybody who gets this issue only when running mysqld by hand to reset the root password, use `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables` instead.

Comment: I got the same issue with mysql-server. I killed all the processes related to mysql(command `ps aux | grep mysql`). Still couldn't solve the issue. Then i went through this answer - https://serverfault.com/a/752681. This almost solved the issue. But without adding `[mysqld]` in my.cnf it won't work. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/q/44298071/8175015. Note: Restart the server using `service mysql start` after updating my.cnf

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Fixed. Add `skip-external-locking` to `my.cnf` under the `[mysqld]` section, and then reboot the entire system. This should fix it, for anyone who finds this. Also if you backed up your data, then attempted to restore and were told to `rm ib*` to make it work, you need the `ibdata` file.

Comment: How can this be the accepted answer. Are things totally differen in verison 5.7?

Comment: This is the accepted answer because it's the only solution that worked for me that was suggested here. Also it's my question and my answer and I accepted it. And i can't speak for 5.7.

Comment: My research shows that things changed around 5.7.14 :-(

Comment: See the man pages for the mysql server. skip-external-locking has nothing to do with the sock.lock file.

Comment: Works for me on 5.7.23 running (now) on MacOS X Mojave.

Comment: As SamboyCoding (the same who ask the question) said in the question comments:  "t's fixed now anyway: serverfault.com/questions/751277/mysql-daemon-lock-issue. " This is the right answer so I'm updating this. I tried to increase RAM, SWAP, on a new ubuntu 20 install and this was the only thing that stopped the problem.  File in Ubuntu is at /etc/mysql/my.cnf and it didn't have the [mysqld]  line so i added the 2 lines.

Answer (score 83):

I just ran into this. The mysql install was a little weird and was missing
/var/run/mysqld/

MySQLd was attempting to create the socket and lock file but the parent directory was missing. I simply created the directory

```
sudo mkdir /var/run/mysqld
```

chowned it to mysql

```
sudo chown mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld
```

I was then able to start mysqld normally.

Comment: This solved my issue. I had run mysql using supervisorctl. It was working fine, until somehow the directory went missing. Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: As I faced this issue on a seemingly fresh Ubuntu 20.04 VPS. First i checked that /run/mysqld exist, and that made me change every occurence of `/var/run/mysqld` to `/run/mysqld` inside **/etc/mysql**. After that the apt-get -f install went well.

Anyway i assume the VPS had maybe some unusual defaults, that could lead to the split brain of /run and /var/run

Answer (score 6):

I experienced the same issue today on my Ubuntu server. But I think the solution is NOT to disable locking. In my case, a look at the system log (`dmesg | tail` and `journalctl -xe`) revealed that it's an apparmor issue and the solution can be found [in this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/751277/mysql-daemon-lock-issue).

Comment: Yes, but as I stated in the comments section, I did not have any AppArmor or anything like that. It was just being plain weird.

Answer (score 5):

I had following error

> ```
> [ERROR] Unix socket lock file is empty /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock.lock.
> ```

This error came up as a result that my server was lacking space 100% use (see below)

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      41153856 28531384  12187364  100% /
```

**Make sure the folder exists with the proper permissions**

```
chown mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/
```

**And make sure to delete the file so the mysql server could generate a new one**

```
rm /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock.lock
```

Answer (score 4):

Posting this answer, in case it helps someone with the same config as me. I had similar issue with this configuration:

Host OS: `Ubuntu 20.04`, MySql server: `8.0`

The following error was seen in `/var/log/mysql/error.log` during run of `systemctl start mysql`

```
[ERROR] [MY-010273] [Server] Could not create unix socket lock file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock.lock.
```

Fix was similar:

```
mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld/
chmod 777 /var/run/mysqld/
```

And of course, I had enough space wherever mysql server was being installed.

Comment: Yeah, I solved my problem in the same way. It's very wired that Ubuntu 20 didn't create this folder after `apt install mysql-server`.

Comment: For those coming to this a bit later, `chmod 777 /var/run/mysqld` is not so good. Much better is `chown mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld`

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I restarted my system and this error literally surprised me.

Answer (score 2):

Below commands worked for me.

```
sudo mkdir /var/run/mysqld

sudo chmod 777 /var/run/mysqld -R
```

Comment: For those coming to this a bit later, `chmod 777 /var/run/mysqld` is not so good. Much better is `chown mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld`

Answer (score 1):

Also may be out of disk space.

Comment: For those coming to this a bit later, `chmod 777 /var/run/mysqld` is not so good. Much better is `chown mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld`

Answer (score 1):

For those running docker. If you're already running mysql in docker, you will also get such an error. Removing the mysql container solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to look at the **log files** (/usr/local/var/mysql/*.local.err) before attempting any of the more generic answers.

---

In my case first it complained of not being able to open the socket file (`[Server] Could not open unix socket lock file /tmp/mysql.sock.lock.`) and once I changed permissions, it complained of not being able to remove it! (`[Server] Could not remove unix socket lock file /tmp/mysql.sock.lock errno 13.`)

Removed it and run mysql.server start and DONE.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this since my solution was just a bit different.  After moving the Mysql data directory to a different partition I ran into socket lock file creation issues that were resistant to permission setting and file touching.  I think with some hunting I might have found the config updates necessary to make moving /etc/var/mysql work, but since time was a factor  I just created a new empty /etc/var/mysql folder and made mysql.mysql the owner with chmod.  Mysql started right up.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Rename /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock.lock & /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock to /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock.lock.bck & /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock.bck respectively and start mysqld. It works

Answer (score -1):

If you are using docker to run MySQL, please check if there is enough allocated disk space in docker preferences.