# mysql says root@localhost is created with an empty password ! But nothings happening. did I miss something?

Tags: mysql, macos, macos-sierra

This started off as a root password resetting exercise- but been running into various errors: Currently stuck at conflicts on 3306 port. See last few paras of the question if you want to skip the previous steps (I just kept updating the question & title as I made progress). Thank you.

I have a mac with mysql installed- but I cant remember the password hence I've been trying to reset it using: `https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html` `(section:B.5.3.2.2 Resetting the Root Password: Unix and Unix-Like Systems)`.

While running this command:
`mysqld --init-file=/home/me/mysql-init &`

I got this error:

```
`[1] 70374
Deepaks-MacBook-Air:data root# 2018-05-06T08:35:29.269289Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2018-05-06T08:35:29.271535Z 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled
2018-05-06T08:35:29.272815Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.21) starting as process 70374 ...
2018-05-06T08:35:29.290319Z 0 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2018-05-06T08:35:29.290429Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!

2018-05-06T08:35:29.290472Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2018-05-06T08:35:29.290494Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2018-05-06T08:35:29.293896Z 0 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete

[1]+  Done(1)`
```

Hence I'm trying this command: 
`sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start --init-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysql-init`

but now I'm getting this error: 
`ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/Deepaks-MacBook-Air.local.pid).`

The following is the content of the log file:

```
2018-05-06T08:03:52.799002Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2018-05-06T08:03:52.801385Z 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled
2018-05-06T08:03:52.801495Z 0 [Note] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.21) starting as process 69954 ...
2018-05-06T08:03:52.810622Z 0 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/mysql/data/ is case insensitive
2018-05-06T08:03:52.832273Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2018-05-06T08:03:52.832306Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2018-05-06T08:03:52.832313Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2018-05-06T08:03:52.832319Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2018-05-06T08:03:52.832780Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2018-05-06T08:03:52.833783Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2018-05-06T08:03:52.838027Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2018-05-06T08:03:52.856588Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2018-05-06T08:03:52.876537Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2018-05-06T08:03:52.899436Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2018-05-06T08:03:52.900043Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2018-05-06T08:03:52.944160Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2018-05-06T08:03:52.946174Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2018-05-06T08:03:52.946218Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2018-05-06T08:03:52.946641Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2018-05-06T08:03:53.001405Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.21 started; log sequence number 2551377
2018-05-06T08:03:53.001712Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /usr/local/mysql-5.7.21-macos10.13-x86_64/data/ib_buffer_pool
2018-05-06T08:03:53.001962Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2018-05-06T08:03:53.019470Z 0 [Warning] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key
2018-05-06T08:03:53.020660Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 180506 13:33:53
2018-05-06T08:03:53.026724Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2018-05-06T08:03:53.026844Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2018-05-06T08:03:53.026872Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2018-05-06T08:03:53.026926Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2018-05-06T08:03:53.087999Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2018-05-06T08:03:53.088163Z 0 [Note] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.21'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2018-05-06T08:12:46.664218Z 2 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2018-05-06T09:35:55.013341Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 2948657ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=0 and evicted=0, during the time.)
```

Whats wrong and how to fix this?

PS: I've been referring to these two SO, and am trying nearly all solutions in all answers- reseting permissions to removing all files in `/usr/local/var/mysql`. It still the same issue, I suspect its something to do with mysqld not running properly- is there a special way to run it as root. I'm currently trying to run in root mode in terminal by `sudo -i`. Can someone help me debug this? Thanks

mysql version:

```
> mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.21, for osx10.12 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

UPDATE: I read the security documentation- apparently you aren't supposed to run it as root mode. So I logged out using `exit`.

Now, I'm getting the following situation:

```
Deepaks-MacBook-Air:mysql deepak$ mysqld --init-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysql-init &
[2] 72004
Deepaks-MacBook-Air:mysql deepak$ mysqld: Can't change dir to '/usr/local/var/mysql/' (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
2018-05-06T10:59:48.877152Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2018-05-06T10:59:48.880902Z 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled
2018-05-06T10:59:48.881775Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.21) starting as process 72004 ...
2018-05-06T10:59:48.897332Z 0 [Warning] Can't create test file /usr/local/var/mysql/Deepaks-MacBook-Air.lower-test
2018-05-06T10:59:48.897395Z 0 [Warning] Can't create test file /usr/local/var/mysql/Deepaks-MacBook-Air.lower-test
2018-05-06T10:59:48.897593Z 0 [ERROR] failed to set datadir to /usr/local/var/mysql/
2018-05-06T10:59:48.897607Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2018-05-06T10:59:48.897624Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2018-05-06T10:59:48.899188Z 0 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

which I suspect is due to the removal of my /usr/local/var/mysql directory as was suggested in one of the other answers. I'd deleted that using `rm -rf`. I made an new dir `mkdir mysql` in `var` and ran `mysqld --init-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysql-init &`, and it initially gives me a pid but then the logs ask me if 3306 port is already occupied:

```
2018-05-06T11:04:14.215705Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
2018-05-06T11:04:14.218651Z 0 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
2018-05-06T11:04:14.225038Z 0 [Note] Salting uuid generator variables, current_pid: 72031, server_start_time: 1525604653, bytes_sent: 0, 
2018-05-06T11:04:14.225601Z 0 [Note] Generated uuid: '36553708-511d-11e8-ba65-c83fe4b8ed7b', server_start_time: 1828179975261387404, bytes_sent: 140216128435712
2018-05-06T11:04:14.225667Z 0 [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: 36553708-511d-11e8-ba65-c83fe4b8ed7b.
2018-05-06T11:04:14.241961Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2018-05-06T11:04:14.391057Z 0 [Note] Auto generated SSL certificates are placed in data directory.
2018-05-06T11:04:14.391874Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2018-05-06T11:04:14.490103Z 0 [Note] Auto generated RSA key files are placed in data directory.
2018-05-06T11:04:14.499147Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
2018-05-06T11:04:14.499239Z 0 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
2018-05-06T11:04:14.499424Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2018-05-06T11:04:14.499495Z 0 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Address already in use
2018-05-06T11:04:14.499503Z 0 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2018-05-06T11:04:14.499536Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

I actually have two folders in my `/usr/local/` -  `mysql` and `mysql-5.7.21-macos10.13-x86_64`. The whole process so far, I've been running in the 'mysql`folder and haven't really touched`mysql-5.7.21-macos10.13-x86_64`. They seem to have the same directory structure inside.

Also when I do `ps aux | grep mysql`, I get three processes:

```
Deepaks-MacBook-Air:local deepak$ ps aux | grep mysql
deepak           72071 100.0  0.0  2443044   1992 s002  S+    4:44PM   0:00.01 grep mysql
_mysql           71985   0.0  0.2  2852472  13132   ??  Ss    4:25PM   0:00.66 /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --user=_mysql --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin --log-error=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.err --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.pid --keyring-file-data=/usr/local/mysql/keyring/keyring --early-plugin-load=keyring_file=keyring_file.so
root             71967   0.0  0.1  2460804   7992 s002  T     4:23PM   0:00.03 sudo mysqld --init-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysql-init
```

However, when I proceed to kill the second or the third one, they simply reappear when I do ps aux again.

Also, I usually use a portforwarding to connect to a remote MySQL host. So, every once a while and in local scripts I run `"ssh -fNT -L 3307:localhost:3306 -i ~/key/deepak_ubuntu_16feb.pem ubuntu@ec2-AWS-HOS-TNA-ME.compute-1.amazonaws.com"`

Could this be a conflict?

UPDATE:
OK, I ignored the other directory and simply changed the port, that seemed to now avoid the conflict, but now has a different problem: mysql.sock.lock cant be accessed?

```
Deepaks-MacBook-Air:mysql deepak$ mysqld --init-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysql-init --port=3308 &
[2] 72160
Deepaks-MacBook-Air:mysql deepak$ 2018-05-06T11:32:45.441642Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2018-05-06T11:32:45.443453Z 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled
2018-05-06T11:32:45.444202Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.21) starting as process 72160 ...
2018-05-06T11:32:45.463651Z 0 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2018-05-06T11:32:45.478310Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2018-05-06T11:32:45.478366Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2018-05-06T11:32:45.478375Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2018-05-06T11:32:45.478384Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2018-05-06T11:32:45.480830Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2018-05-06T11:32:45.483263Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2018-05-06T11:32:45.487576Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2018-05-06T11:32:45.507092Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2018-05-06T11:32:45.538289Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2018-05-06T11:32:45.565701Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2018-05-06T11:32:45.565987Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2018-05-06T11:32:45.622322Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2018-05-06T11:32:45.623627Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2018-05-06T11:32:45.623652Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2018-05-06T11:32:45.623974Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2018-05-06T11:32:45.678385Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.21 started; log sequence number 1209980
2018-05-06T11:32:45.678936Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /usr/local/var/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2018-05-06T11:32:45.680200Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2018-05-06T11:32:45.680346Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 180506 17:02:45
mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
2018-05-06T11:32:45.680885Z 0 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
2018-05-06T11:32:45.684081Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2018-05-06T11:32:45.686185Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
2018-05-06T11:32:45.686212Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.
2018-05-06T11:32:45.691365Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2018-05-06T11:32:45.691562Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
2018-05-06T11:32:45.693912Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3308
2018-05-06T11:32:45.694589Z 0 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
2018-05-06T11:32:45.694853Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2018-05-06T11:32:45.695047Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open unix socket lock file /tmp/mysql.sock.lock.
2018-05-06T11:32:45.695067Z 0 [ERROR] Unable to setup unix socket lock file.
2018-05-06T11:32:45.695092Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

OK, so I went into `/tmp/` and tried to check permissions of the file- below are the results:

```
Deepaks-MacBook-Air:tmp deepak$ stat mysql.sock.lock 
16777220 3413029 -rw------- 1 _mysql wheel 0 6 "May  6 16:25:35 2018" "May  6 16:25:35 2018" "May  6 16:25:35 2018" "May  6 16:25:35 2018" 4096 8 0 mysql.sock.lock
Deepaks-MacBook-Air:tmp deepak$ stat mysql.sock
16777220 3413030 srwxrwxrwx 1 _mysql wheel 0 0 "May  6 16:25:44 2018" "May  6 16:25:44 2018" "May  6 16:25:44 2018" "May  6 16:25:35 2018" 4096 0 0 mysql.sock
```

I'm trying the solutions from this SO post `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34954455/mysql-daemon-lock-issue`, the change owner answer did not work. I'm a little hesitant to remove locking.

OK, this post: `https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/checking-linux-file-permissions-with-ls/` quite neatly explains how to read those permissions- apparently in my case _mysql user and wheel are the owner and group respectively. That doesn't make sense because I've never come across `wheel` in anything out side a `.whl` context and I haven't encountered the _mysql before today. I've tried to change to that user earlier using `su - _mysql` and I couldn't guess the password- not sure if mysql sets this up by default, in which case I'm confused right about now.

UPDATE:
OK, I solved that my Chowning it:

```
Deepaks-MacBook-Air:tmp deepak$ sudo chown deepak mysql.sock
Deepaks-MacBook-Air:tmp deepak$ sudo chown deepak mysql.sock.lock
Deepaks-MacBook-Air:tmp deepak$ stat mysql.sock.lock
16777220 3413029 -rw------- 1 deepak wheel 0 6 "May  6 16:25:35 2018" "May  6 16:25:35 2018" "May  6 17:26:54 2018" "May  6 16:25:35 2018" 4096 8 0 mysql.sock.lock
Deepaks-MacBook-Air:tmp deepak$ stat mysql.sock
16777220 3413030 srwxrwxrwx 1 deepak wheel 0 0 "May  6 16:25:44 2018" "May  6 16:25:44 2018" "May  6 17:26:22 2018" "May  6 16:25:35 2018" 4096 0 0 mysql.sock
```

However, that gives rise to another error:
`Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist`.

```
Deepaks-MacBook-Air:mysql deepak$ mysqld --init-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysql-init --port=3308 &
[2] 72244
Deepaks-MacBook-Air:mysql deepak$ 2018-05-06T11:57:33.454182Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2018-05-06T11:57:33.456455Z 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled
2018-05-06T11:57:33.457505Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.21) starting as process 72244 ...
2018-05-06T11:57:33.470925Z 0 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2018-05-06T11:57:33.482170Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2018-05-06T11:57:33.482216Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2018-05-06T11:57:33.482224Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2018-05-06T11:57:33.482231Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2018-05-06T11:57:33.486263Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2018-05-06T11:57:33.489217Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2018-05-06T11:57:33.494624Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2018-05-06T11:57:33.513877Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2018-05-06T11:57:33.546517Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2018-05-06T11:57:33.575022Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2018-05-06T11:57:33.575404Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2018-05-06T11:57:33.620985Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2018-05-06T11:57:33.622662Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2018-05-06T11:57:33.622693Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2018-05-06T11:57:33.623068Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2018-05-06T11:57:33.677963Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.21 started; log sequence number 1209999
2018-05-06T11:57:33.679157Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /usr/local/var/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2018-05-06T11:57:33.680426Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 180506 17:27:33
2018-05-06T11:57:33.681987Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
2018-05-06T11:57:33.684004Z 0 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
2018-05-06T11:57:33.688066Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2018-05-06T11:57:33.690386Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
2018-05-06T11:57:33.690502Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.
2018-05-06T11:57:33.694745Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2018-05-06T11:57:33.694856Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
2018-05-06T11:57:33.695461Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3308
2018-05-06T11:57:33.696028Z 0 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
2018-05-06T11:57:33.696184Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2018-05-06T11:57:33.700436Z 0 [Warning] Failed to open optimizer cost constant tables

2018-05-06T11:57:33.704524Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist

2018-05-06T11:57:33.704983Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Alright, that got resolved by changing the owner from _mysql to my normal account using `chown` but now the the issue is:

```
Deepaks-MacBook-Air:mysql deepak$ mysqld --initialize-insecure --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --init-file=/usr/local/mysql/mysql-init --port=3308 &
[2] 72328
Deepaks-MacBook-Air:mysql deepak$ 2018-05-06T12:21:01.547203Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2018-05-06T12:21:01.550869Z 0 [ERROR] Can't find error-message file '/usr/local/mysql-5.7.21-macos10.13-x86_64/share/mysql/errmsg.sys'. Check error-message file location and 'lc-messages-dir' configuration directive.
2018-05-06T12:21:01.557694Z 0 [ERROR] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
2018-05-06T12:21:01.557751Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Here is how I resolved this: the share folder didn't have a mysql directory and instead had the errmsg.sys in the english directory, I simply copied this file into a new directory I created in the share folder: `mkdir mysql`.

This worked but then showed:

```
Can't create directory '/usr/local/mysql/data/' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2018-05-06T12:49:13.313038Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2018-05-06T12:49:13.316262Z 0 [Warning] Using pre 5.5 semantics to load error messages from /usr/local/mysql-5.7.21-macos10.13-x86_64/share/mysql/.
2018-05-06T12:49:13.316285Z 0 [Warning] If this is not intended, refer to the documentation for valid usage of --lc-messages-dir and --language parameters.
2018-05-06T12:49:13.322333Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Using chown, I changed the owner of mysql directory to my regular user account (strangely the mysql-5.7.21-macos10.13-x86_64 directory would not change its owner from group from root and wheel to anything even if I sudo'ed it.

So now the `mysqld --initialize-insecure --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --init-file=/usr/local/mysql/mysql-init --port=3308 &` command from `/usr/local/mysql/` shows the following output:

```
Deepaks-MacBook-Air:local deepak$ mysqld --initialize-insecure --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --init-file=/usr/local/mysql/mysql-init --port=3308 &
[2] 72460
Deepaks-MacBook-Air:local deepak$ 2018-05-06T12:52:51.009693Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2018-05-06T12:52:51.013089Z 0 [Warning] Using pre 5.5 semantics to load error messages from /usr/local/mysql-5.7.21-macos10.13-x86_64/share/mysql/.
2018-05-06T12:52:51.013108Z 0 [Warning] If this is not intended, refer to the documentation for valid usage of --lc-messages-dir and --language parameters.
2018-05-06T12:52:51.020232Z 0 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/mysql/data/ is case insensitive
2018-05-06T12:52:51.549560Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45790
2018-05-06T12:52:51.614133Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
2018-05-06T12:52:51.692927Z 0 [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: 630bcd34-512c-11e8-934a-45e8be00c2cf.
2018-05-06T12:52:51.711501Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2018-05-06T12:52:51.847929Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2018-05-06T12:52:51.903182Z 1 [Warning] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
```

This seemed good but nothing is happening. Is this it? Can I start connecting using my SequelPro to 'localhost:3308' now? or is there some other caveats I need to resolve like setting temp password? Before even that, do I need to go into another terminal window to try `mysql -u root` and leave this running or what?

Also, when I don `ps aux | grep mysql` it shows three processes as before but does not show `72460` the one that mysqld just showed me now. Is this something I need to be concerned about?

This is the first time I'm doing this, and I'm scared to do anything right about now to not ruin the last few hours of efforts to fix this.

How do I resolve this? Thanks!

UPDATE: FINAL ISSUES:

OK, I'm dealing with a final set of issues, gonna ask in a seperate question.

1)
    Deepaks-MacBook-Air:App deepak$ mysql -u root
    ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

and

2)

```
Deepaks-MacBook-Air:App deepak$ mysqladmin -u root
mysqladmin  Ver 8.42 Distrib 5.7.21, for osx10.12 on x86_64
Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Administration program for the mysqld daemon.
Usage: mysqladmin [OPTIONS] command command....
```

3) In my System Preferences > MySQL, it says "`MySQL server instance is STOPPED`".

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the issue with running as root is that mysqld doesn't want to have root privileges. You're not wrong to run it as root though, since the data directory should by default not be writable to your own user. Simply tell it to drop privileges and run as the "mysql" user, which is the default user mysqld runs under on macOS and likely the user who owns the data directory (note that "_mysqld" and "mysql" refer to the same user on macOS for historical reasons). You do this by adding `-u mysql` to mysqld's command line.

The two directories should really be only one directory (with the long name that includes a version number) and one symbolic link (/usr/local/mysql pointing to the directory). That's how the MySQL installer sets things up, the symlink always points to the latest version of MySQL that was installed.

The other mysqld you see running is the one started from launchd. This is also something the MySQL installer sets up. You can use the MySQL preference pane (which should be installed by default) to shut it down. Otherwise, macOS will keep restarting it because it interprets the shutdowns as random failures. The preference pane should be somewhere at the end of the bottom row in System Preferences.

The port forwarding thing should not be an issue. It will only be active while the ssh connection is up, and it doesn't even forward the same local port.

Comment: Hey Snowcat, I'm a through and through self taught dev, and I've taught myself only what I've needed to know at each point- so I guess there are gaps in my knowledge- and so this kind of stuff helps a lot. Thank you!