# Could not open unix socket lock file /tmp/mysql.sock.lock on executing mysql.server start

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

### Summary:

Unable to execute mysql.server start, and the error log seems to be a bit off from what I see online.

The local.err file shows the error as below after executing mysql.server start:

```
ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file
```

```
[ERROR] [MY-010274] [Server] Could not open unix socket lock file /tmp/mysql.sock.lock
[ERROR] [MY-010268] [Server] Unable to setup unix socket lock file
```

### What I have tried:

I tried creating these two files with

```
touch mysql.sock.lock
touch mysql.sock
```

Unfortunately, this did not solve the problem.

I've also tried reinstalling mysql couple of times, but it did not work as well.

```
brew uninstall mysql
brew update
brew install mysql
```

### Expected result:

Login to MySQL and be able to use it with rails application.

If anybody knows how to solve this issue, please send me a help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try this solutions from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46779157/11164996)